validation to avoid overlapping of text not working inside squares
Following steps need to be followed in order for the code to work.

Select one option from Select options dropdown.
Select a color from the dropdown.
Click Show Options button
Enter a row and column (For example A and 1) and then click calculate
Hit the Move Text Content! button to move blue boxes on the grid.
Forget about barcode and plate name for this problem.

Scenario I'm trying to validate:
Let's say I have option one related content on cell A1, A2 and A3 and option two related content starting from B1.
Note: the order in which the cell contents are filling are left to right and from bottom to up. Hence, when I hit the Move Text Content button to fill 7 blue boxes on the grid starting from B1, it will look like this.

As you can see, the last two items OptionTwo#6 and OptionTwo#7 got overlapped with already present text on A1 and A2. So I'm trying to handle this edge case scenario and I was approaching it this way (code snippet below from the actual code):
myButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        /* To Validate:
        Case #1: If the cell value for starting square already exists
        then, you cannot fill it. Show an alert. 
        
        Case #2: Check for all the values that are about to be moved on to
        the squares. If any of these overlap with already existing value of the grid
        then you cannot fill it. Show an alert
        */

        /* Get all values that need to be tested 
       */

        var childDivs = document
            .getElementById("phrase")
            .querySelectorAll("div:has(> span[data-id])");

        console.log(childDivs);

        // get the calculated value of the cell number
        let testValue = document.querySelector("#cellnum").innerHTML;

        console.log("Test Value");
        console.log(testValue);
        let integerValue = parseInt(testValue);

        // create an array of values to be tested.
        const valueArray = [];
        for (i = 0; i < childDivs.length; i++) {
            valueArray.push(integerValue + i);
        }



        for (j = 0; j < valueArray.length; j++) {
            var getDivWithValue = document
                .getElementById("drop-em")
                .querySelectorAll('div:has(> span[data-id="' + valueArray[j] + '"])');



            if (getDivWithValue.length > 0) {
                console.log("A value already exists for cell value " + valueArray[j]);

                alert("Starting Square or other Square needed to complete the move are already in use.Please use different Starting Cell Value");
                return;
            }
        }


        fill();
    },

    );

What's the issue with the above approach?
Here is my complete working code:


/*

Requires jquery + UI

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js

*/

$('[name="optionSelection"]').change(function () {
      //clean up the divs inside div with id phrase
    $("#phrase").empty();
  });
let selectedColor;
  function showOptions() {
      selectedColor = $('#lineupColors').val();
    var html;
    if ($("#optionSelection").val() == 1) {
      for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         
            html = "<div data-id="+i+"><span class='words' style='color:black;background-color:white'  data-id="+i+">OptionOne#"+i+"</span></div>";
            $("#phrase").append(html);
      }
      
    }
    else {
      for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
         
        html = "<div data-id="+j+"><span class='words'  style='color:black;background-color:white' data-id="+j+">OptionTwo#"+j+"</span></div>";
       $("#phrase").append(html);
    }
   // $("#phrase").append(html);
  }
}


  $(".words").draggable({
    revert: function (event, ui) {
      var bRevertingPhrase = this.closest("#drop-em");

      if (!bRevertingPhrase.length) {
        var phraseID = $(this).data("id");
        var phraseHomeID = $(this).parent().data("id");

        //If the child and parent ids don't match, we move the child to the correct parent
        if (phraseID !== phraseHomeID) {
          var correctCell = $("#phrase").find(
            "div[data-id='" + phraseID + "']"
          );
          correctCell.prepend(this);
        }
      }
      return !event;
    },
  });
  $("#drop-em > div").droppable({
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable)
        .detach()
        .css({ top: 0, left: 0 })
        .appendTo($(this).find(".content:empty"));
      //$("#move-text").addClass("disabled");
    },
  });
  $("#phrase > div").droppable({
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable).detach().css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).prependTo(this);
    },
  });

  const myButton = document.querySelector("#move-text");
  myButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        /* To Validate:
        Case #1: If the cell value for starting square already exists
        then, you cannot fill it
        
        Case #2: Check for all the values that are about to be moved on to
        the squares. If anyone of these overlap with already existing value of the grid
        then you cannot fill it
        */

        /* Get all values that needs to be tested 
       */

        var childDivs = document
            .getElementById("phrase")
            .querySelectorAll("div:has(> span[data-id])");

        console.log(childDivs);

        // get the calculated value of the cell number
        let testValue = document.querySelector("#cellnum").innerHTML;

        console.log("Test Value");
        console.log(testValue);
        let integerValue = parseInt(testValue);

        // create an array of values to be tested.
        const valueArray = [];
        for (i = 0; i < childDivs.length; i++) {
            valueArray.push(integerValue + i);
        }



        for (j = 0; j < valueArray.length; j++) {
            var getDivWithValue = document
                .getElementById("drop-em")
                .querySelectorAll('div:has(> span[data-id="' + valueArray[j] + '"])');



            if (getDivWithValue.length > 0) {
                console.log("A value already exists for cell value " + valueArray[j]);

                alert("Starting Square or other Square needed to complete the move are already in use.Please use different Starting Cell Value");
                return;
            }
        }


        fill();
    },

    );

  var reOrder = [];
  function fill() {
    const cells = document.querySelectorAll("#phrase > div > span");
    var newLoc = "";
    //myButton.classList.add("disabled");

    cells.forEach((cell, index) => {
      newLoc = document.querySelector(
        ".item:nth-child(" + reOrder[index + startPos - 1] + ") .content "
      );
      newLoc.append(cell);
      newLoc.classList.add("moved");
       newLoc.classList.add("color-"+selectedColor);
      $('.color-'+selectedColor).css('background-color',selectedColor);
      
    });
  }
  function reArrange() {
    var limit1 = 85;
    var limit2 = 91;

    for (let loop = 0; loop < 8; loop++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        reOrder.push(limit1 + i);
      }
      limit1 = limit1 - 12;
    }
    for (let loop = 0; loop < 8; loop++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        reOrder.push(limit2 + j);
      }
      limit2 = limit2 - 12;
    }
  }
  reArrange();

  /* get cell number */

  const myRow = document.querySelector("#inp1");
  const myCol = document.querySelector("#inp2");
  var startPos = 0;
  const myCalculateButton = document.querySelector("#calculate");
  const myAnswer = document.querySelector("#cellnum");
  myCalculateButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var rowNumber = myRow.value.toUpperCase();
    var colNumber = myCol.value;
    var result = 0;
    switch (rowNumber) {
      case "A":
        rowNumber = 42;
        break;
      case "B":
        rowNumber = 36;
        break;
      case "C":
        rowNumber = 30;
        break;
      case "D":
        rowNumber = 24;
        break;
      case "E":
        rowNumber = 18;
        break;
      case "F":
        rowNumber = 12;
        break;
      case "G":
        rowNumber = 6;
        break;
      case "H":
        rowNumber = 0;
        break;
    }

    if (colNumber < 7) {
      result = rowNumber + parseInt(colNumber);
    } else {
      result = rowNumber + 42 + parseInt(colNumber);
    }
    myAnswer.innerHTML = result;
    startPos = result;
  });
  
 
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  body {
    counter-reset: columnCount 1 alphaCount cellCount;
  }
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .wrap {
    display: flex;
    gap: 2rem;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 220px;
  }

  .grid {
    margin: auto;
    display: grid;
    flex: 1 0 0;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
  }

  .item {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    counter-increment: columnCount;
    min-width: 0;
    transition: background 1s ease;
  }
  .item:nth-of-type(12n + 1) {
    counter-increment: alphaCount;
  }
  .item:nth-of-type(12n + 1)::before {
    content: counter(alphaCount, upper-alpha);
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -1.75rem;
    color: red;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .item:nth-of-type(n + 13)::after {
    display: none;
  }
  .item::after {
    content: counter(columnCount);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: -1.75rem;
    color: red;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    color: #000;
    padding: 1rem;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    counter-increment: cellCount;
  }

  .words {
    cursor: move;
    transition: padding 0.5s ease;
   }
     
  .content:has(.ui-draggable-dragging) {
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .ui-droppable-active .content {
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .words.ui-draggable-dragging {
    background: blue;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    z-index: 999;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #phrase {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 1rem 0 0.5rem;
  }
  #phrase > div {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #007bff;
    border: 2px solid #007bff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  #phrase > div:empty {
    background: #fff;
    border-style: dashed;
    padding: 0px 25px;
    min-height: 30px;
  }

  .moved {
    animation: fade 3s ease;
  }
  @keyframes fade {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
      background: red;
    }
  }

  .item .content::before {
    content: counter(cellCount);
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    font-size: smaller;
    color: #666;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: white;
    width: 1.2rem;
    height: 1, 2rem;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
  }

  #move-text.disabled {
    cursor: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  #phrase:has(.ui-droppable-active) {
    overflow: visible;
  }

  input,
  button,
  label,
  p.target {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0.4rem;
    color: #000;
  }
  p.target {
    margin: 0 0 1rem;
  }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <!-- You'd need to set up something different for touch devices though -->

  <h1>Move testings</h1>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div>
      <label for="optionSelection">Select options</label>
      <select name="optionSelection" id="optionSelection">
        <option value="1">OptionOne</option>
        <option value="2">OptionTwo</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="lineupColors">Colors:<br /></label>
    <select id="lineupColors">
       <option value="-">select</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="orange">Orange</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
      <option value="purple">Purple</option>
      <option value="brown">Brown</option>
      <option value="black">Black</option>
      <option value="magenta">Magenta</option>
    </select>
  </div>
    <div>
      <button id="showOptions" onclick="showOptions()" type="button">
        Show Options
      </button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="inp1">Enter a row A - H</label>
      <input id="inp1" placeholder="Enter Row" />
      <label for="inp2">Enter a column 1 - 12</label>
      <input id="inp2" placeholder="Enter Column" />
      <button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
      <p class="target">The cell number is <b id="cellnum">?</b></p>
        <label for="barcode">Barcode</label>
      <input id="barcode" placeholder="" />
        <label for="pName">Plate Name</label>
      <input id="pName" placeholder="" />
      <button id="move-text" type="button">Move Text Content!</button>
    </div>
    <div id="phrase">
      <!-- remove whitespace from  inside div html and then we can use :empty in css to change background -->
      <!-- <div data-id="1"><span class="words" data-id="1">H1 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="2"><span class="words" data-id="2">H2 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="3"><span class="words" data-id="3">H3 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="4"><span class="words" data-id="4">H4 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="5"><span class="words" data-id="5">H5 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="6"><span class="words" data-id="6">H6 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="7"><span class="words" data-id="7">G1 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="8"><span class="words" data-id="8">G2 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="9"><span class="words" data-id="9">G3 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="10"><span class="words" data-id="10">G4 text</span></div> -->
    </div>

    <div id="drop-em" class="grid">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <!-- must have no spaces inside .content -->
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




you have a question with lots of code but not clear intentions on how to solve the issue you described in the scenario when one of those boxes gets moved to a cell already containing one. How are you supposed to deal with that? should the code just put the previously existing box back in the "deck" and replace it with the new one in the target cell?

No. It should just display an alert alert("Starting Square or other Square needed to complete the move are already in use.Please use different Starting Cell Value"); return; and should not let the user move the boxes with overlapping scenarios in the first place.
